# ¿Cómo hago para simplificar un Switch?

Tags: php

Tengo un Switch en el que toma los datos de una base de datos. Y tengo que poner en cada caso que tengo que definir la variable, hay alguna forma de no tener que poner:

```
case '1':$pj_ojos="Castaños";break;
```

```php
<?php
switch($pj_ojos=$row['Ojos'])
{
  case '1':$pj_ojos="Castaños";break;
  case '2':$pj_ojos="Verdes";break;
}
?>
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es conveniente manejar una posible opción por defecto, de hecho, puede que ninguna de las condiciones del `switch` se cumpla.

Si en `$row['Ojos']` recibes un valor inferior o superior a `4` el código fallará, porque no está contemplada esa posibilidad.

Esto se puede hacer aplicando la siguiente lógica:

- Colocando en el índice `0` del array un hipotético valor por defecto, que puede ser lo que quieras: una cadena, `NULL`, `FALSE` ... etc, según tu lógica. De paso, evitamos encontrar el dato restando `1` al índice.
- Usando un *operador ternario* para asignar el valor por defecto cuando no se encuentre un índice válido en el array.

El código sería así:

```
# Array de colores, índice 0 valor por defecto
$theColors = array("Default","Castaños","Verdes","Azules","Marrón");
$idEyes=1; #valor en $row['Ojos']
# Obteniendo dato con un ternario
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes] ) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
# Prueba
echo $eyesColor;
```

Te preguntarás por qué en el ternario se hace un `OR` preguntando si es booleano ¿?  Por un motivo muy simple (y lo veremos cuando sometamos el código a prueba más abajo): si pruebas este código con un dato equivalente a `TRUE` te dirá que los ojos son `Castaños`, porque **PHP convierte los valores booleanos `TRUE` a `1`** para hacer comparaciones.

Dicho esto, sometamos el código a prueba, con varios tipos de valores:

```
$idEyes=1;
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes] ) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
echo $eyesColor.PHP_EOL;

$idEyes=-1;
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes] ) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
echo $eyesColor.PHP_EOL;

$idEyes="aaaa";
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes] ) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
echo $eyesColor.PHP_EOL;

$idEyes=NULL;
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes] ) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
echo $eyesColor.PHP_EOL;

$idEyes=FALSE;
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes] ) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
echo $eyesColor.PHP_EOL;

# Esta es la causa por la cual debe haber una evaluación is_bool en el ternario
$idEyes=TRUE;
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes]) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
echo $eyesColor.PHP_EOL;

$idEyes="";
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes] ) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
echo $eyesColor.PHP_EOL;

$idEyes="200";
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes] ) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
echo $eyesColor.PHP_EOL;

$idEyes=3;
$eyesColor = ( empty($theColors[$idEyes] ) || is_bool($idEyes) ) ? $theColors[0] : $theColors[$idEyes];
echo $eyesColor.PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
Castaños
Default
Default
Default
Default
Default
Default
Default
Azules
```

---

#### Fiddle

Puedes ver una **<kbd>[DEMOSTRACIÓN](https://rextester.com/HTUULV85502)</kbd>**  del código en línea y hacer pruebas sobre él.

#### Conclusión

Tenemos entonces un sustituto real de `switch`, que incluye una opción `default` y que es *typesafe*.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tomarte ese trabajo, pero, en mi caso, jamás podría no cumplirse. No hay opciones, ya que se hace desde un servidor con lenguaje Pawn donde sólo hay select's y no inputs, además que desde mi PHP cree un _if_ que te redirige a otra página si detecta algo extraño.

Comment: @Morderisk entiendo, pero nunca se sabe y mientras más control haya en el código mejor. Además pensé la respuesta para englobar otro tipo de situaciones, por ejemplo que los  valores sean recibidos desde `inputs` escritos a mano y cosas así, o una actualización masiva de una base de datos leyendo en un archivo de texto o csv...

Answer (score 2):

puedes crear un arreglo que contenga los colores de ojos, y luego buscarlos a través del indice

```
<?php

$lista_ojos = array("Castaños","Verdes","Azules","Marrón");

$pj_ojos = $lista_ojos[$row['Ojos']-1];

?>
```

o tambien la version como arreglo de objetos

```
<?php

$lista_ojos = array(1=>"Castaños", 2=>"Verdes", 3=>"Azules", 4=>"Marron");
$pj_ojo = $lista_ojos[$row['Ojos']];

?>
```

esto considerando que el campo 'Ojos' sea un numero valido de 1 a 4

espero te sirva