# ¿Tengo una duda en php sobre elseif?

Tags: php

mi problema es que tengo este sistema.

```
<?php
}
else if($name=="123")
{
echo "<html><h2>Acceso permitido</h2></html>";
}
else
{
echo "<html><h2>El codigo no es valido o ha caducado.</h2><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'>Volver</a></html>";
}
?>
```

Donde pone `else if($name=="123")` quiero que ademas de 123 haga una lista de caracteres ejemplo 123; 445; 23231 ;2334.y que si alguno de esos coincida de acceso permitido. Nose si me explico.

---

No funciona
El codigo completo es este :

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
if(!isset($name) && !isset($pass))
{
?>
<html>
<h2>Necesitas un codigo de acceso</h2>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>
</html>
<?php
}
else if($name=="123")
{
echo "<html><h2>Acceso permitido</h2></html>";
}
else
{
echo "<html><h2>El codigo no es valido o ha caducado.</h2><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'>Volver</a></html>";
}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
$code=$_GET["c"];
?>
<?php
$code = array(
    '123',
    '445',
    '23231',
    '2334',
    //...
);

//...
elseif(in_array($name, $names, true)){
    echo "<html><h2>Acceso permitido</h2></html>";
}
?>
```

Esto es como lo estoy utilizando ahora mismo

Comment: ¿Cuántos `else` tienes?  ¿Por qué no estructuras todo en un array asociativo? [Mira este estilo de solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/237294/29967), es preferible algo así cuando tienes muchos condicionales. [Puedes ver también este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/234720/29967), implementando comprobaciones más complejas.

Comment: No funciona porque llamaste `$code` a tu array y en la comprobación utilizas `$names`. O bien cambia `$code` a `$names` al declarar el array o pon `$code` en el `elseif`... Así debería funcionar con la respuesta dada por @OscarR .  Y no uses esta área para incidencias sobre el código, para eso tienes que editar la pregunta. Esta área es sólo para respuestas.

Answer (score 5):

Hay muchas formas de abordar lo que quieres hacer.

Otra forma es mediante un *array* y comprobar si existe el valor dado.

```
$names = array(
    '123',
    '445',
    '23231',
    '2334',
    //...
);

//...
elseif(in_array($name, $names, true)){
    echo "<html><h2>Acceso permitido</h2></html>";
}
```

Más información sobre *in_array*: http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 4):

Algo asi?:

```
if($name=='123' || $name=='445' || $name=='23231')
    echo "<html><h2>Acceso permitido</h2></html>";
else
    echo "<html><h2>El codigo no es valido o ha caducado.</h2><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'>Volver</a></html>";
```

En el `if()`, lo que estás haciendo es comparar posibles cadenas que el usuario introduce, si es alguna de la que aparece en la **condición**, entra en el `if()` y muestra Acceso permitido.
Mientras que si no coindicen ninguna, entrará en el `else` y mostrará código no es válido y te reedirigirá al enlace de **javascript.**

Comment: Responder con solo código sin explicar se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Mi +1 lo tienes... Puedes contestar como quieras Alvaro... no te dejes influir ni acosar de algunos sheriff's de aquí... no hay ni buena ni mala calidad... porque es todo muy objetivo! Gracias y diviértete aquí! Qué es lo que cuenta!! Saludos

Comment: @BlackSheep no creo que el comentario de element haya sido hecho con la intención de "acosar" o por creerse superior. Él tiene razón en lo que dice, de hecho eso provocó una mejora de la respuesta que aporta calidad a la misma y a este sitio. Su comentario es por tanto constructivo. El tuyo por el contrario no lo es al juzgar mal y descalificar algo que se ha hecho con buena intención para todos. Saludos.

Comment: No me sentí acosado en ningún momento a la hora de que me dijera lo de comentar el código, de hecho, tiene razón. Pero supongo que posiblemente se pueda decir de otra forma, pero repito, no me sentí ni acosado ni presionado. Estamos aquí todos para aprender.

Comment: Tienes razón Álvaro, te comento y recomiendo este enlace [answer] saludos y gracias por la observación siempre es bien recibida

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$code=$_GET["c"];
?>
<?php
if($code=='123' || $code=='445' || $code=='23231')
    echo "<html><h2>Acceso permitido</h2></html>";
else
    echo "<html><h2>El codigo no es valido o ha caducado.</h2><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'>Volver</a></html>";
?>
```

Al final este es el que me ha servido aun que preferiria hacerlo con arrays (por el orden). Gracias a todos :)